# Arduino + ESP8266 as Webserver

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, web-server

I want to connect Arduino to my Home Wifi and make it serve as a server to access GPIO pins on Arduino from remote (like controlling LED connected to Arduino from remote).
I am using ESP8266 to connect to my wifi network.
I am facing some issues like:

- sometimes it doesn't connect to my wifi router.
- not connecting to my mobile Hotspot.
- not able to serve default and AP mode.

I am following tutorial from http://allaboutee.com/2014/12/30/esp8266-and-arduino-webserver/
Here is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
#define DEBUG true

SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3); // make RX Arduino line is pin 2, make TX Arduino line is pin 3.
                             // This means that you need to connect the TX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 2
                             // and the RX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 3
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(115200); // your esp's baud rate might be different



  sendData("AT+RST\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // reset module
//  sendData("AT",2000,DEBUG); // send AT command
//  sendData("AT+GMR\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // returns firmware
//  Serial.println("checking mode");
//  sendData("AT+CWMODE=?\r\n",5000,DEBUG); // check supported modes
//
//  Serial.println("scanning APs");
//  sendData("AT+CWLAP\r\n",21000,DEBUG); // scan list of access points

  Serial.println("set mode 1");
  sendData("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n",5000,DEBUG); // configure as both mode

//  Serial.println("joining AP");
  sendData("AT+CWJAP=\"<MY_WIFI_SSID>\",\"<WIFI_PASSWORD>\"\r\n", 16000, DEBUG); // connect to wifi

  Serial.println("Testing CIFSR");
  sendData("AT+CIFSR\r\n",7000,DEBUG); // get ip address

  Serial.println("setting for multiple connection");
  sendData("AT+CIPMUX=1",2000,DEBUG); // configure for multiple connections

  Serial.println("print MAC address");
  sendData("AT+CIPSTAMAC?\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // print current MAC address

  Serial.println("set port 80 for server");
  sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1\r\n,80",2000,DEBUG); // turn on server on port 80
}

void loop()
{
  if(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message 
  {

    if(esp8266.find("+IPD,"))
    {
     delay(2000);

     int connectionId = esp8266.read()-48; // subtract 48 because the read() function returns 
                                           // the ASCII decimal value and 0 (the first decimal number) starts at 48

     String webpage = "<h1>Tyagi IoT</h1><button>LED1</button>";

     String cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
     cipSend += connectionId;
     cipSend += ",";
     cipSend +=webpage.length();
     cipSend +="\r\n";

     sendData(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
     sendData(webpage,1000,DEBUG);

     webpage="<button>LED2</button>";

     cipSend = "AT+CIPSEND=";
     cipSend += connectionId;
     cipSend += ",";
     cipSend +=webpage.length();
     cipSend +="\r\n";

     sendData(cipSend,1000,DEBUG);
     sendData(webpage,1000,DEBUG);

     String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE="; 
     closeCommand+=connectionId; // append connection id
     closeCommand+="\r\n";

     sendData(closeCommand,3000,DEBUG);
    }
  }
}


void sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{
    esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266
    long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
      {
        // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
        Serial.write(esp8266.read());
      }  
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but posting my 2 cents for future visitors. You're setting "AT+CWMODE=1" which is Client mode. Mode 3 is the correct one for both client and server mode.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an arduino (as in UNO / mini / nano etc.) and communicating with a separate esp8266 via serial?
I've found esp8266 module to be more reliable by using a 12e or such like and running arduino boot loader on it. There's more memory to play with, and I tend to formulate the data I need within the ESP8266 and then communicate with that via serial or I2C to get data / requests to and from.

Make sure you're supplying the ESP module with enough current - they're juicy little things, so good 300mA @3.3v and use a good 470uf 10v cap or something too.. They can splurge current on occasion, particularly when scanning networks.

Let me know what set up you're running

Cheers

Comment: Using Uno and communicating using AT commands on Software serial as mentioned in the code above.

Comment: If you're running the esp straight off the uno 3.3v power supply, that'll be the first thing to change. The esp8266 can draw around 200mA transmitting and around 60mA when receiving. The 3.3v regulator built into the arduino UNO is rated for like 50mA max from memory, so defo get a better 3.3v supply. I usually use a MIC5219 LDO regulator which is good for around 500mA but super efficient. Gotta sort power out before trying anything else at this point :)